# How to get the value of title from span using Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have this code

```
followers_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[2]/a/span')
```

[image: title value]

I need to get value of title from span. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print the *value* of the *title* attribute you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class*='na13'][href='/top_ukraine_girls/followers/']>span").get_attribute("title"))
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='-na13' and @href='/top_ukraine_girls/followers/']/span").get_attribute("title"))
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class*='na13'][href='/top_ukraine_girls/followers/']>span"))).text)
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='-na13' and @href='/top_ukraine_girls/followers/']/span"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

Answer (score 1):

```
print(followers_button.get_attribute('title'))
```

I am assuming you want to get the title attribute value using get_attribute and not the text.

Outputs:

```
114 555
```

Answer (score 0):

In case `/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[2]/a/span` is a corrct XPath locator

```
followers_button_text = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[2]/a/span').text
print(followers_button_text)
```

Should work