# VBA Selenium Dynamic ID (Wildcard)

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

Is there a possibility to find an element by ID with an wildcard?
I have something like this:

```
stat = GC.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='C29_W88_V90_V94_admin_status']").Value
stat = GC.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='C26_W88_V90_V94_admin_status']").Value
stat = GC.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='C29_W88_V12_V94_admin_status']").Value
```

The `admin_status` part won't change but the values before.
Sometimes I have the same problem with another element with values around it. So the best thing would be to find the element with some wildcard like this:

```
stat = GC.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='*admin_status*']").Value
```

Comment: See this ...  https://devhints.io/xpath

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use XPath contains() here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064968/how-to-use-xpath-contains-here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is tested in Excel VBA using Selenium.

```
Option Explicit
Sub sbXPathContains()
    Dim driver As ChromeDriver
    Set driver = New ChromeDriver
    Dim sURL As String
    sURL = "https://davetallett26.github.io/table.html"
    Call driver.Start("edge")
    driver.get (sURL)
    driver.Window.Maximize
    sbDelay (100000)
    MsgBox driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[contains(@id, 'ctl03_txtCash')]").Attribute("outerHTML")
    '                                 //* = any element  contains  @id = within id  'ctl03_txtCash' = string to find   .Attribute("outerHTML") = return HTML of the element
    sbDelay (100000)
    driver.Quit
End Sub

Sub sbDelay(delay As Long): Dim i As Long: For i = 1 To delay:  DoEvents: Next i: End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

As the value of the ***id*** attribute contains dynamic values, you need to counstruct dynamic [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver) as follows:

- Using *FindElementByCss* and *contains* clause:

  ```
  stat = GC.FindElementByCss("[id*='admin_status']").Value
  ```
- Using *FindElementByCss* and *ends with* clause:

  ```
  stat = GC.FindElementByCss("//*[id$='admin_status']").Value
  ```
- Using *FindElementByXPath* and *contains* clause::

  ```
  stat = GC.FindElementByXPath("//*[contains(@id, 'admin_status')]").Value
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions related to [*Dynamic Locator Strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71713359/7429447) in:

- [How to find element by part of its id name in selenium with python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59637443/7429447)
- [How to get the value of title from span using Python and Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70086521/7429447)
- [Java Selenium webdriver expression finding dynamic element by ccs that starts with and ends with](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65893830/7429447)